# How a plan is split into Job and stage in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to understand how a query plan is splitted into job in Spark, how spark decide to split the workflow in job and stage.

My query is a simple join between a big table (22Gb) and a small table (300Mb):

```
select key0 from BigTable,SmallTable where importedKey=keySmallTable
```

and i execute it with ShuffledHashJoin and BroadcastHashJoin.

For ShuffledHashJoin i get only one job:

[image]

And 4 Stage:

[image]

For  BroadcastHashJoin i get 3 job:

[image]

And 4 stage:

[image]

[image]
[image]

This Job's division is caused by the "collect" on the driver that is required when i use a BroadcastHashJoin?

Comment: _This Job's division is caused by the "collect" on the driver that is required when i use a BroadcastHashJoin?_ -  yes. Broadcasting requires data collection and subsequent distribution to the workers.